# Is there any way to create an online form to create tasks to planner?

Tags: forms, api, office365, microsoft-planner, microsoft365

I'm new to microsoft planner 365 and I think it's a great tool.

I do not want users to access my plan (board). Is there any way I can create an online form that can be shared to other users to allow them to submit requests and it adds tasks directly to a bucket category?

(Except using Power Automate?

Answer (score 0):

using forms and Power Automate this can be setup in less than 5 minutes using the below template that is provided.

[image]

if you have reasons for not taking the simple approach, then of course you can build the same using a mirad of other tools and technologies.
As a final step then [create the Task Using the Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example)